# libVLC displays green screen in Visual Studio (but same stream is fine in VLC)

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I'm using [libVLCSharp](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp) in my Windows Forms application.

For this I checked out these NuGet packages:

- [VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows/)
- [LibVLCSharp.WinForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibVLCSharp.WinForms/)

Here is my initialization code snippet:

```
private static string[] libVLCParams = { "--rtsp-tcp", "--verbose=2" };
private LibVLC libVLC;

private void Initialize() {
    Core.Initialize();
    libVLC = new LibVLC(libVLCParams);
}
```

I added a VideoView to my Form1, initialized a new MediaPlayer object for it, then to start the stream to play:

```
...
VideoView.MediaPlayer.Play(new Media(libVLC, sampleURI, FromType.FromLocation));
...
```

Here is my log regarding this stream playing: https://pastebin.com/UVD7Juk3

However the stream after the first valid picture corrupts and shows a full green screen:

[image]

When I try to play the same stream in VLC program (same PC, same video), it **plays smooth and fine**.

Here are my VLC settings:

[image]

[image]

I also have restarted the PC, and my stream sources, but no luck.

## What cause this type of image distortion and how can I resolve it?

Comment: What version of VLC? Can you share the VLC logs when it works?

Comment: Green screen is most often a hardware acceleration problem. Try disabling it on the mediaplayer